# SQL select order by desc

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my sql query i just want my sellingPrice from sale table in descending order 
Need help Thanks in advance.

e.g.

```
SELECT salesMan.salesmanID, salesMan.name, SUM(sale.sellingPrice)
FROM salesMan 
INNER JOIN sale ON salesMan.salesmanID = sale.salesManID
GROUP BY salesmanID, name;
```

Comment: why dont you use `...SELECT * FROM .....` and then use a while loop.(CODING SIMPLIFIED)

Comment: @Mr.coder Because this is like 90% simpler, probably?

Comment: yeah so simpler code will reduce confusions

Comment: @Mr.coder Using `...SELECT * FROM...` is just wrong. You can read more about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: @Yoda i gave him that solution in the belief that he is using all the columns in his mysql table

Comment: @Mr.coder Even if you are using all columns in a table it is better to specify them.

Comment: @Mr.coder: seems like getting the resultset needed from the database would actually simplify the code **more** than writing code to "roll your own" `GROUP BY` and `SUM` operations. Seems like it would be more efficient too. With a smaller resultset for MySQL to prepare, fewer rows to fetch, and opportunity for the DBA to optimize for this query.

Comment: @spencer7593 i didnt understand anything you said

Comment: @Mr.coder: Then maybe you shouldn't be advising people on database operations.  But basically: let the database do the things it's good at, like grouping and summing data.  It's silly to offload that to PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Then add:

```
order by SUM(sale.sellingPrice) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the alias to the `SUM` column and use it to order your result set.

```
Select salesMan.salesmanID,salesMan.name, SUM(sale.sellingPrice) as sellingPriceSum
FROM salesMan INNER JOIN
     sale
     ON salesMan.salesmanID = sale.salesManID
GROUP BY salesmanID,name
ORDER BY sellingPriceSum desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Select salesMan.salesmanID, salesMan.name, SUM(sale.sellingPrice) AS totalSale
FROM salesMan INNER JOIN
     sale
     ON salesMan.salesmanID = sale.salesManID
GROUP BY salesmanID, name
ORDER BY totalSale DESC;
```

You can simplify the query like this:

```
SELECT sm.salesmanID, sm.name, SUM(s.sellingPrice) AS totalSale
FROM salesMan sm 
INNER JOIN sale s ON sm.salesmanID = s.salesManID
GROUP BY sm.salesmanID, sm.name
ORDER BY totalSale DESC;
```